# D3 is there a global data array

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to find out if there is a global data array created in D3. I need to be able to access it from anywhere. I have  Jquery slider params that I pass to an update function. I will be using the indexes to redraw the chart.Or do I have to create this global myself?

```
function redraw(first,last) {
            var chart = d3.select(".chart");
  // this only grabs one rect so I only have one value for _data_
               var rect = chart.selectAll("rect");
```

EDIT: I want the original data so that I can filter it and rerender (See my comment below). But it doenst seen to be in the global space for me to access it.

Comment: The short answer is no. You need to be able to select all the elements you're interested in to retrieve their data.

Comment: That deserves to be an answer, @LarsKotthoff.  OP asked a yes/no question.  You answered it.

Comment: @Mars I'm not entirely sure what OP means, so I want to clarify before posting an answer.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, OK.  You're right--it's not clear.  I was imposing an interpretation.  mike628, what kind of data do you mean?  Data that you loaded? (In that case, whether there's a global reference to it depends on how you loaded it.)  DOM objects (e.g. SVG objects, HTML objects)? But they're probably not in an array as such.  They're in a tree.  `d3.select<All>` is a way to find things in the tree.  How did you want to be able to access the data?

Comment: mike628, BTW you can get different combinations of elements with `d3.selectAll()` [depending on how you reference them](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections).  Your first call with `d3.select` searches by class.  The second call, with `d3.selectAll()` searches by SVG tag.  There are other options, including logical operations.  Creative use of class and id names can help as well.  I'm not sure whether that addresses your issue, though.

Comment: Just cleaning up the answers for clarity: A short answer: Data is bound to DOM in a tree data structure, which provides global access. Selection methods provide accessibility.

Comment: I loaded the data using d3.tsv and rendered it. now I need to update it in relation to the slider. So I have an update function that gets called by the JQuery function stop: function( event, ui ) {redraw(ui.values[ 1 ],ui.values[ 1 ]);}  I need access to the dataset within "redraw". But its not available in the JQuery slider function.

Comment: So select the elements and get the data -- `d3.selectAll("rect").data()`

Comment: @mike628 Or make a global var?

Comment: I guess I was looking for best practices. I plan on making a Dashboard.